# How can I enable mods in Cities Skylines?

Tags: mods, cities-skylines

I am hoping not to sound too much of a nitwit, but I am completely not understanding how mods are supposed to work on Cities Skylines (or Steam at all for that matter). I find confusing information: some sites telling me to download files (which ones?) some hinting towards subscribing to be enough (I guess...)

To be a little more specific, all I want is to be able to use the right mouse button to pan in the game. That's it. I found [this mod](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1406625743) that supposedly does that, but there is nothing I can download, so I subscribed, and started the game. Nothing. Nowhere anything about mods at all in the game.

Another option would be [this mod](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2327536070), which seems to be a little more recent, but same problems apply here.

In short, how do I install mods (or manage them) in Cities: Skylines?

Comment: Hi Bart, usually mods go into a specific folder. I don't know about this particular game, but does this help at all?
https://skylines.paradoxwikis.com/Folder_Structure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Windows OS

To install mods in the Cities Skylines usually, I will do this.

### In the browser

1. Log in to Steam and navigate to the mod, e.g.
   https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1406625743
2. Subscribe to the mod
3. Once that is done, the Steam client automatically download the subscribed mod in the game computer/laptop

### On the computer (I am using Windows 10, should work for Windows 8.1 too)

4. Open Cities Skylines - Play
5. On the screen, you will find **Content Manager**. Select it.
6. In the Content Manager screen you will find the **MODS** on the left side. Select it.
7. On the right side, you need to enable the mod you want to be available in the game. Refer [this image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBaWS.jpg) for the screens.
8. To uninstall a mod, you can unsubscribe it either from the Steam Workshop page (where you previously subscribed) or from the **MODS** section of the Content Manager screen by clicking **x** button on the right side.

## Note

Due to some reason, if you couldn't find your subscribed mod in the *MODS* section of the content manager, sign out the Steam client on your machine and sign in again.

Comment: This works for linux as well.

Comment: There's Skyve now.